# Table multiplication in Angular using ngFor

Tags: angular, multiplication, ngfor

I'm trying to display the table based on the input value but when displaying the result I'm getting the last value instead of the entire result as its a for loop.

Here is my multiplytable.component.ts

```
export class multiplytableComponent implements OnInit{
  result!:any;
  calcnums =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
  calculate(tablenumber:string){
    for(let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      const result = i * parseFloat(tablenumber);
      this.result= `${parseFloat(tablenumber)} * ${i} = ${result}`;
      console.log(`${parseFloat(tablenumber)} * ${i} = ${result}`);
  }
  }
```

This is my multiplytable.component.html

```
Enter Table Number: <input type="text" #tablenumber />
<button (click)="calculate(tablenumber.value)">Multiply Table</button>
<h3 *ngFor="let val of calcnums">{{result}}</h3>
```

This is the output I'm getting
[image]

Comment: this appears to be [tag:angular].  The older [tag:angularjs] has been deprecated for many years at this point.

Comment: Yup sorry will update tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for loop should start with zero and end with `<` condition as shown in the below condition.

Also we need to loop through the `results` array instead of the original array, this is for performance purposes, on button click the values will get set and rendered!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    Enter Table Number: <input type="text" #tablenumber />
<button (click)="calculate(tablenumber.value)">Multiply Table</button>
<h3 *ngFor="let val of result; let i = index;">
  {{val}}</h3>
  `,
})
export class App {
  result: any = [];
  calcnums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  calculate(tablenumber: string) {
    this.result = [];
    if (tablenumber && +tablenumber !== 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.result.push(this.getContent(tablenumber, this.calcnums[i]));
      }
    }
  }

  getContent(val: any, i: number) {
    return `${parseFloat(val)} * ${i} = ${i * parseFloat(val)}`;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ungaht)

Comment: One more thing it takes only the first input and if I enter second number it dosent take it and how do I clear the values if there is no input

Comment: @coder added an if condition, that stops empty values, kindly check the updated answer!